# Best practice for passing info from a collectionview to a segued view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm looking for a best practice for selecting an item from a collectionview and segueing to an "item detail" view controller.

I'd like to send an index value (let's say an int) to that detail view controller, and let it load the proper information when it viewDidLoads.

I've done a couple of things for this in the past (pre-segue) all of which seemed kind of hacky to me (i.e. having a static variable in the AppDelegate), but I'd like to know a right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to use prepareForSegue:sender:. If the segue is attached from a cell, then the sender argument will be the cell, and you can get the indexPath using the UICollectionView method, indexPathForCell:. You can then pass that value or use it to query your data source, and pass something you extract from it.

Comment: I wouldn't pass the indexPath - that leaks the abstraction. It's probably better to pass the object that the cell is displaying information for.

Comment: @Anorak, I agree. I only included that because that's what the OP said he wanted.

Comment: @Anorak I might not want to get full objects at the time.  The collection view would have a much smaller request, and the detail vc would make a secondary larger web service request -- which is why I wanted to pass the index.  I suppose I could then request the full object to pass it along, but I prefer to do that from the destination.